# How to combine a list of cuminc curves? E.g. using ggcompetingrisks?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am plotting cumulative incidence of relapse (CIR) and cumulative incidence of curve, using cuminc {cmprsk}. Is there a way of combining the two curves in the same graph? ONE graph but TWO curves.

Comment: Please, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can have the curves in the same graph by turning off multiple panels in the `ggcompetingrisks()` function

```
ggcompetingrisks(cuminc, multiple_panels=FALSE)
```